Lombok Builder return interface type
I have a class that implements an Interface. This class has a @SuperBuilder annotation from Lombok that returns an object of this class, obviously. But what I really need is that it returns an object of the Interface type. Is it possible to configure?
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class MyClass extends AbstractMyClass implements MyInterface {
}

This is what I get:
MyClass obj = MyClass.builder().build();

This is what I expect:
MyInterface obj = MyClass.builder().build();


Why do you need that to be interface type? an instance of that class IS also an instance of that interface. Nothing is stopping you from writing your own implementation

tldr: there is a clean maintainable lombok-solution to this using @Delegate which is from lombok.experimental (but since you already use SuperBuilder, that is not a new dependency).
You can usually customize a builder by writing parts of it by hand, lombok will generate the rest. This is a bit easy to mess up, so the best technique for customizing lombok-behaviour is usually to delombok that part of your code, make your modification, remove the rest of the delomboked code, and add your lombok-annotations back in. Let's try it on this structure:
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
abstract class Animal {
    private String name;
}

interface GoodBoy {
    void getStick();
}

@SuperBuilder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
class Dog extends Animal implements GoodBoy {
    private boolean isGoodBoy;

    @Override
    public void getStick() {/* ... */}
}


class Test {
    GoodBoy dog = Dog.builder().build();
}

First note that you can already create the interface from the builder - of course you can, because every dog is already a GoodBoy by virtue of the Dog-class implementing the GoodBoy-interface.
Now what I assume you want to ban is this code:
Dog dog = Dog.builder().build()

I do not know why you would want to do that, but whatever. If we delombok the @SuperBuilder on the Dog-class we get this:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
class Dog extends Animal implements GoodBoy {
    private boolean isGoodBoy;


    @Override
    public void getStick() {/* ... */}

    protected Dog(DogBuilder<?, ?> b) {
        super(b);
        this.isGoodBoy = b.isGoodBoy;
    }

    public static DogBuilder<?, ?> builder() {
        return new DogBuilderImpl();
    }
    public static abstract class DogBuilder<C extends Dog, B extends DogBuilder<C, B>> extends AnimalBuilder<C, B> {
        private boolean isGoodBoy;

        public B isGoodBoy(boolean isGoodBoy) {
            this.isGoodBoy = isGoodBoy;
            return self();
        }

        protected abstract B self();

        public abstract C build();

        public String toString() {
            return "Dog.DogBuilder(super=" + super.toString() + ", isGoodBoy=" + this.isGoodBoy + ")";
        }
    }

    private static final class DogBuilderImpl extends DogBuilder<Dog, DogBuilderImpl> {
        private DogBuilderImpl() {
        }

        protected DogBuilderImpl self() {
            return this;
        }

        public Dog build() {
            return new Dog(this);
        }
    }
}

We can not easily change this build()-method to return another type, or we would have to change all that generic/inheritance code (and more or less just end up writing our own builder-pattern). We want to keep using lombok so we have to make the change somewhat minimal. We can also not make a subclass of the Builder to return a GoodBoy instead of a dog, as return types are covariant (you can return a more narrow type in a subclass, but you cannot return a wider type). The only solution I can see is to write another class that wraps the existing class and delegates all its methods. lombok.experimental has @Delegate which is handy in this case (if you have to write the delegate yourself, might as well write the builder yourself and ditch lombok).
You customize the static builder-function, and add the wrapper-class, but the difficult and hard-to-maintain rest can come from lombok. The dog-class now looks like this:
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
class Dog extends Animal implements GoodBoy {
    private boolean isGoodBoy;


    @Override
    public void getStick() {/* ... */}


    public static GoodBoyBuilderImpl builder() {
        return new GoodBoyBuilderImpl();
    }


    public static final class GoodBoyBuilderImpl {
        @Delegate
        @Getter
        DogBuilderImpl impl;

        public GoodBoyBuilderImpl() {
            impl = new DogBuilderImpl();
        }

        public GoodBoy build() {
            return impl.build();
        }
    }
}

This has the desired behaviour, while keeping all methods from the builder without you having to write them.
    Dog dog = Dog.builder().build(); // Error!
    GoodBoy goodBoy = Dog.builder().build(); // works.


"if you can use lombok.experimental" SuperBuilder is already experimental, and they use that in the question.

@Michael good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Unfortunately, Lombok's @SuperBuilder annotation doesn't directly support this behavior out of the box. You can create a static factory method in the MyClass class to achieve this.
Here's how you can modify your code:
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class MyClass extends AbstractMyClass implements MyInstance {
 
    // Your class fields and methods
    
    public static MyInstanceBuilder builder() {
        return new MyClassBuilder();
    }
}

Since MyInstanceBuilder extends MyClassBuilder, it can still be used to build instances of MyClass.
However, the return type of the builder() method is MyInstanceBuilder, allowing you to use it to build instances of the interface type (MyInstance).
Now, you can create instances like this:
MyInstance obj = MyClass.builder().build();


How would that work? You don't show MyInstanceBuilder.

MyInstance interface has not Builder...
